# RaisePropertyChanged is not working

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm

I have a button whose content is binded with ViewModel's property called Test.

```
<Button Content="{Binding Test, Mode=TwoWay}"  
            Name="button1"Click="button1_Click" />
```

On click of the button I am changing its content

```cs
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.Content = "Yellow";
}
```

But in the property setter I would like to override the content being set and set my own content.
Following is the code for same:

```cs
string _test;
public string Test
{
    get
    {
        return _test;
    }
    set
    {
        _test = "Something" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Test);
    }
}
```

Now the problem is button's content is getting set as "Yellow" instead of that it should be something like "Something..."

If I bind this property with textbox at the same time, there the value is being displayed in the correct manner.

**Note:** this is just an example and focus of my question is raisepropertychanged.

Please help.

Comment: Is your setter really setting a field called `test`, or should this be `_test`, as used by the getter?

Comment: Yeah it is _test. Sorry for typo. I have corrected it in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your answers. I have figured out that it worked when you run it in the Non-debug mode. But in case of Call Back it will not work even in non-debug mode.

I have finally got the solution which mentioned in the article http://info.titodotnet.com/2011/08/silverlight-dependency-property-clr.html

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

That's a really weird setter, you really shouldn't do something like that. If I set `Test = "Yellow"`, I would expect it to be `Yellow`, not something completely different. You should put the code that updates the property into a separate method and call the from your event handler:

```cs
string _test;
public string Test
{
    get
    {
        return _test;
    }
    private set
    {
        _test = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Test);
    }
}

public void UpdateTest()
{
    Test = "Something" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateTest();
}
```

Comment: Actually I have some validation to perform before setting the property if validation is fine only then i will allow the property to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your

```
button1.Content = "Yellow";
```

is removing the binding to your ViewModel.

You should not be setting `button1`'s content directly in the view, but rather setting the content of the ViewModel, which will update the View accordingly.

Comment: Exactly, it you want to update the button content, change the value of the property "Test" that you're binding to. The Binding will update button1.Content automatically.

Comment: No it wont remove the binding. However I have just figured out that this will work in non-debug mode perfectly.

Comment: This is a valid scenario when you have custom control instead of button. Because in custom control you can have multiple button and would like to update a property and on the property change the consumer of the custom control would like to validate and revert the same.